# Multiple date ranges based on a bit value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have below table with data

```
id departmentid  ischanged date
3   22             0      2014-01-04
3   101            0      2014-01-05
3   125            1      2014-01-06
3   169            1      2014-01-07
3   175            0      2014-01-08
3   176            0      2014-01-09
3   177            0      2014-01-10

5   22             0      2014-01-04
5   101            0      2014-01-05
5   125            0      2014-01-06
5   169            0      2014-01-07
5   175            0      2014-01-08
5   176            0      2014-01-09
5   177            0      2014-01-10
```

and my current query is

```
insert into #temp1(id, startdate, enddate)
SELECT t1.id, '2014-1-4' as startdate, min(isnull(enddate,'2014-01-10')) as endDate
FROM (
            SELECT id, departmentid, ischanged
            FROM dbo.[table]    where date = '2014-1-4'
      ) AS t1
        left join 
        (
            SELECT id, departmentid, ischange , date
            FROM dbo.[table]    where date >= '2014-1-4'
        ) as t2
         on t1.id = t2.id and (t1.ischange <> t2.ischange)
group by t1.id
```

and will result in the following output, if the `ischange` is not changed then it will grab the hard coded end date from the query, otherwise it will grab the least `ischange` value changed date

```
id  startdate      enddate
3   2014-01-04    2014-01-05
5   2014-01-04    2014-01-10
```

but I looking for a result set like this

```
id  startdate      enddate
3   2014-01-04    2014-01-05
3   2014-01-08    2014-01-10
5   2014-01-04    2014-01-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the periods where `ischanged` is 0.  You can do this using differences of `row_number()`:

```
select id, min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by id order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by id, ischanged order by date)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
where ischanged = 0
group by id, grp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But don't know how to use your solution in my query